# Remove N first rows of a column from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

if I have a DataFrame of length 3, with 3 columns

```
a b c
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Is there a smart way to replace the first 2 rows of column `b` with NaN?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### `pd.Series.mask`.

```
df['b'] = df.b.mask(df.index < 2)
df

   a    b  c
0  1  NaN  3
1  4  NaN  6
2  7  8.0  9
```

If your `df.index` is not a monotonically increasing integer index, then you can replace `df.index` with `np.arange(len(df))` -

```
df.b.mask(np.arange(len(df)) < 2)

0    NaN
1    NaN
2    8.0
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

---

#### `np.where`

```
df['b'] = np.where(df.index < 2, np.nan, df.b)
df

   a    b  c
0  1  NaN  3
1  4  NaN  6
2  7  8.0  9
```

---

#### `np.ndarray.__getitem__`

Similar to Wen's `iloc`, indexing on numpy arrays -

```
i = df.b.values
i[:2] = np.nan

df['b'] = i    
df

   a    b  c
0  1  NaN  3
1  4  NaN  6
2  7  8.0  9
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED Thanks for the help, I went with option 3, since it was probably best to mention I were using Datetime as index

Comment: @vandelay No problem. I kinda figured that could happen. The first two solutions are still valid if you substitute with `arange`. Anyway, the 3rd option should be extremely fast for large data too. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

```
df.b.iloc[:2]=np.nan
df
Out[481]: 
   a    b  c
0  1  NaN  3
1  4  NaN  6
2  7  8.0  9
```

Comment: The :-1 should be n=2; n+1 looking at the question, right? Anyway +1